# Using MSSQL tool sqlcmd, is it possible to set a row delimiter?

Tags: sql-server, bash

Using bash, I use the sqlcmd MSSQL tool.

When a query returns more than one row, these rows are only separated by space, making it impossible to extract the rows from each others, as the data can contain spaces.

Is there a way to tell in the SQL query that I want the rows separated by a specific delimiter ?

Current output:

```
row1filed1, row1field with space, row1other field row2field1, row2field2, row2etc
```

Expected output (with say delimiter = |)

```
row1filed1, row1field with space, row1other field|row2field1, row2field2, row2etc
```

Comment: There is only column separator availble in `sqlcmd` alternative is to use  `sed/awk` to create rows

Comment: or if available you can use The bulk copy program utility `bcp`

Comment: @DigvijayS If you know a way with sed/awk, please share. As said in question, spaces in data mess everything up.

Comment: Are your column values seprated by `,` ? If yes what is the number of columns

Comment: @DigvijayS I do not know the number of column, unless I first check table structure. But I see where you are heading. Thanks.